# Where on GitLab.com do I find the pipeline error logs?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've been working on getting a .gitlab-ci.yml pipeline to work but cannot find where the logs go.

GitLab.com message tells me

```
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-05-06T09_39_43_597Z-debug.log
```

I do not see this folder created on my project within GitLab.com so where and how do I get to the log?

After 51 iterations I have made a little bit of progress. 1st time seeing Green.
[image: little bit of progress]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be seen by adding debug logging to your .gitlab-ci.yml file.Once you add it ,run the job again and you can get a detailed log

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#enable-debug-logging

Answer (score 4):

You could use [artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifacts) to keep the log file, if the job fails. For example:

```yaml
my job:
  ...
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - "*.log"
    when: on_failure
```

I'm not sure the `paths` pattern is correct. So, perhaps, it is neccessary to use `**/*.log` instead of `*.log`. But I hope, the idea is clear.

Comment: Would this add logs to the files that are stored in the repo? I'm not clear on where it would place the .log files and how to access them.

Comment: @edjm, no, the artifact will be attached to the job when it fails. It's possible to browse or [dowload](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#download-job-artifacts) job artifacts from the job page.